# how to separate sentence[i] (string) into words(string) in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have a problem. In my project, I take sentence line by line from dataset file which has one sentence each line. Then , I should separate sentences into words. But I couldn't find this how can I do.

This are the codes of class which will read from dataset:

```
class Input{
...
public:
string *word;
string *sentence;
Couple *couple;    // int x , int y  order of sentence and word
int number;
int line;
...
void readInput(string input);
}
```

This are the codes of read method:

```
void Input::readInput(string input)
{
cout << "Reading the " << input <<endl;

ifstream infile;
infile.open(input.c_str());

    if(!infile.is_open()){
    cerr << "Unable to open file: " << input << endl << endl;
    exit(-1);
}

for(int i=0; i<line ; i++){
    getline(infile, sentence[i]);
    //infile >> sentence[i];
}

for(int j=0;j<line ;j++){
// I want to separate sentences into words
}    

infile.close();
cout << "Finished Reading the " << input <<endl;
```

}

Comment: Are you asking us to do the programming task?

Comment: How can I separate sentences (string) into words(string)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int j=0; j<line; ++j)
{
    std::istringstream iss(sentence[j]);
    for (std::string w; iss >> w; )
    {
        word[number] = w;
        ++number;
    }
}
```

You'll need to do something about punctuation though, if you don't want those attached to your words.  Simple enough I think.

Comment: `for(int j=0;j<line ;j++){
    istringstream iss(sentence[j]);

    do
    {
        iss >> word[number];
        number++;
    } while (iss);

    
    }`

Comment: `for(int j=0;j<line ;j++){
 istringstream iss(sentence[j]); 
do {
 iss >> word[number]; 
number++; 
} while (iss); 
}`
Thanks it worked but after sentences program makes a space (as word), what can I do?

Comment: for example
`From
fairest
creatures
we
desire
increase,
// should not be space here
That
thereby
beauty's
rose
might
never
die,
// should not be space here
But
as
the
riper
should
by
time
decease,
// should not be space here
`

Comment: @BurakDağlı: You re-arranged it in such a way that it adds a word even after the input fails.  See my update for a more correct version for your case.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me in the method where you have:

```
for(int j=0;j<line ;j++){
    // I want to separate sentences into words
}
```

I would use a regex to match all words in `sentence[j]` [boost regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/libs/regex/doc/introduction.html) is a library I have used with great success in the past.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to loop through the std::string representing each line by looking for end-of-word markers using std::string::find_first_of(). The parameter to find_first_of would the set of characters that are used to separate words in your text file(could be space, period etc.).